# Trigger a button with both Click and Enter key for fetching Javascript

Tags: javascript, submit-button

I've been looking for different solutions on the site, but none seem to work for me.
I need to trigger a submit button with Enter keypress event and mouse click, in order to fetch data from a weather api.

```
<div class="inputdiv">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City, Country" id="cityinput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add" onclick="">
</div>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Here's the js:

```
let inputval = document.querySelector('#cityinput')
let btn = document.getElementById('add')

inputval.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
if (event.key === "Enter") {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("add").click();
      
     fetch('......')
```

When I press Enter it works, but I can't find a way to fetch even clicking the button.

Comment: Any reason to avoid setting it as the input's `onclick`?

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle][1]

you can call a certain function onClick and inside your listener


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/L2reck04/

Comment: wrap your form inputs with [<form>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) tag, add button with `type='submit'` attribute. Then attach `submit` even listener to your form using JS and call e.preventDefault() to prevent default behavior..

Answer (score 1):

The button is an input of `type="submit"` which by default triggers a page reload, either make it a `<button>` or keep it an `<input type="submit" />` but then in this case you'll have do a `event.preventDefault()` followed by the desired logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the inputs inside a form . Then enter will find first `submit` button and will trigger click

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Pressed")

});
```

```html
<div class="inputdiv">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City, Country" id="cityinput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add">
  </form>
</div>
```